# Differences between MSIL and Java bytecode?

Tags: java, .net, bytecode, cil

I'm new to .Net and I'm trying to understand the basics first. What is the difference between MSIL and Java bytecode?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453610/javas-virtual-machine-and-net-framework

Comment: A slightly more general comparison is at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682608/implementing-c-sharp-for-the-jvm

Answer (score 83):

First off let me say that I don't think that the subtle differences between Java bytecode and MSIL is something that should bother a novice .NET developer. They both serve the same purpose of defining an abstract target machine which is a layer above the physical machine being used in the end.

MSIL and Java bytecode are very similar, in fact there <strike>is</strike> was a tool called [Grasshopper](http://web.archive.org/web/20150713013105/http://dev.mainsoft.com:80/) which translates MSIL to Java bytecode, I was part of the development team for Grasshopper so I can share a bit of my (faded) knowledge.
Please note that I stopped working on this around when .NET framework 2.0 came out so some of these things may not be true any more (if so please leave a comment and I'll correct it).

- .NET allows user defined types that have value semantics as apposed to the *regular* reference semantics  (`struct`).
- .NET supports unsigned types, this makes the instruction set a bit richer.
- Java includes the exception specification of methods in the bytecode. Although exception specification is usually only enforced by the compiler, it may be enforced by the JVM if a class loader other than the default one is used.
- .NET generics are expressed in IL while Java generics only use [type erasure](http://safalra.com/programming/java/wrong-type-erasure/).
- .NET attributes have no equivalent in Java (is this still true?).
- .NET `enums` are not much more than wrappers around integer types while [Java `enums`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) are pretty much fully fledged classes (thanks to [Internet Friend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18037/internet-friend) for commenting).
- .NET has `out` and `ref` parameters.

There are other language differences but most of them are not expressed at the byte code level, for example, if memory serves, Java's non-`static` inner classes (which do not exist in .NET) are not a bytecode feature, the compiler generates an additional argument to the inner class's constructor and passes the outer object. The same is true for .NET lambda expressions.

Comment: Regarding attributes - Java annotations can be set to appear in the bytecode as well, so there is an equivalent.

Comment: @Oak: Java annotations only allow to pass data, while .NET attributes are fully powered classes, which may have logic and, most importantly, implement interfaces.

Comment: Bytecode also has separate return instructions for every kind of return type, dunno if it actually aids in type safety.

Comment: The fact that value types in .NET may sometimes be allocated on the stack is of trivial importance compared to the fact that they have *value semantics*; every value-type storage location *is* an instance.  By contrast, every storage location in Java is either a primitive or a promiscuous object reference; there are no other types.

Comment: Was wondering how they compare performance wise? Is MSIL faster to interpret then bytecode for eg?

Answer (score 28):

[CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) (the proper name for MSIL) and Java bytecode are more the same than they are different. There are some important differences though:

1) CIL was designed from the beginning to serve as a target for multiple languages. As such, it supports a much richer type system including signed and unsigned types, value types, pointers, properties, delegates, events, generics, an object-system with a single root, and more. CIL supports features not required for the initial CLR languages (C# and VB.NET) such as global functions and [tail-call optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). In comparision, Java bytecode was designed as a target for the Java language and reflects many of the constraints found in Java itself. It would be a lot harder to write C or Scheme using Java bytecode.

2) CIL was designed to integrate easily into native libraries and unmanaged code

3) Java bytecode was designed to be either interpreted or compiled while CIL was designed assuming JIT compilation only. That said, the initial implementation of [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) used an interpreter instead of a JIT.

4) CIL was designed ([and specified](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm)) to have a human readable and writable assembly language form that maps directly to the bytecode form. I believe that Java bytecode was (as the name implies) meant to be only machine readable. Of course, Java bytecode is relatively easily decompiled back to the original Java and, as shown below, it can also be "disassembled".

I should note that the JVM (most of them) is more highly optimized than the CLR (any of them). So, raw performance might be a reason to prefer targeting Java bytecode. This is an implementation detail though.

Some people say that the Java bytecode was designed to be multi-platform while CIL was designed to be Windows only. This is not the case. There are some "Windows"isms in the .NET framework but there are none in CIL.

As an example of point number 4) above, I wrote a toy Java to CIL compiler a while back. If you feed this compiler the following Java program:

```
class Factorial{
    public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(new Fac().ComputeFac(10));
    }
}

class Fac {
    public int ComputeFac(int num){
    int num_aux ;
    if (num < 1)
        num_aux = 1 ;
    else 
        num_aux = num * (this.ComputeFac(num-1)) ;
    return num_aux ;
    }
}
```

my compiler will spit out the following CIL:

```
.assembly extern mscorlib { }
.assembly 'Factorial' { .ver  0:0:0:0 }
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit Factorial extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
   .method public static default void main (string[] a) cil managed
   {
      .entrypoint
      .maxstack 16
      newobj instance void class Fac::'.ctor'()
      ldc.i4 3
      callvirt instance int32 class Fac::ComputeFac (int32)
      call void class [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
      ret
   }
}

.class private Fac extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
   .method public instance default void '.ctor' () cil managed
   {
      ldarg.0
      call instance void object::'.ctor'()
      ret
   }

   .method public int32 ComputeFac(int32 num) cil managed
   {
      .locals init ( int32 num_aux )
      ldarg num
      ldc.i4 1
      clt
      brfalse L1
      ldc.i4 1
      stloc num_aux
      br L2
   L1:
      ldarg num
      ldarg.0
      ldarg num
      ldc.i4 1
      sub
      callvirt instance int32 class Fac::ComputeFac (int32)
      mul
      stloc num_aux
   L2:
      ldloc num_aux
      ret
   }
}
```

This is a valid CIL program that can be fed into a CIL assembler like `ilasm.exe` to create an executable. As you can see, CIL is a fully human readable and writable language. You can easily create valid CIL programs in any text editor.

You can also compile the Java program above with the `javac` compiler and then run the resulting class files through the `javap` "disassembler" to get the following:

```
class Factorial extends java.lang.Object{
Factorial();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   getstatic   #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   3:   new #3; //class Fac
   6:   dup
   7:   invokespecial   #4; //Method Fac."<init>":()V
   10:  bipush  10
   12:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method Fac.ComputeFac:(I)I
   15:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
   18:  return

}

class Fac extends java.lang.Object{
Fac();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public int ComputeFac(int);
  Code:
   0:   iload_1
   1:   iconst_1
   2:   if_icmpge   10
   5:   iconst_1
   6:   istore_2
   7:   goto    20
   10:  iload_1
   11:  aload_0
   12:  iload_1
   13:  iconst_1
   14:  isub
   15:  invokevirtual   #2; //Method ComputeFac:(I)I
   18:  imul
   19:  istore_2
   20:  iload_2
   21:  ireturn
}
```

The `javap` output is not compilable (to my knowledge) but if you compare it to the CIL output above you can see that the two are very similar.

Comment: It turns out there have been attempts to create a human readable/writable Java assembly language. Two that I have found are [Jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/) and [Java Bytecode Assembler](http://tinf2.vub.ac.be/~dvermeir/courses/compilers/javaa/)

Comment: I've written one here that's much better. Unlike Jasmin, it's designed to be able to disassemble and reassemble any valid classfile. https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau. I think it'd be more accurate to say that Microsoft provides a standard assembler while Java coders have to make their own.

Answer (score 24):

They are essentially doing the same thing, MSIL is Microsoft's version of Java bytecode.

The main differences internally are:

1. Bytecode was developed for both compilation and interpretation, while MSIL was developed explicitly for JIT compilation
2. MSIL was developed to support multiple languages (C# and VB.NET, etc.) versus Bytecode being written for just Java, resulting in Bytecode being more similar to Java syntactically than IL is to any specific .NET language
3. MSIL has more explicit delineation between value and reference types

A lot more information and a detailed comparison can be found in [this article by K John Gough](http://web.archive.org/web/20080730224644/http://sky.fit.qut.edu.au/~gough/VirtualMachines.ps) (postscript document)

Comment: "1.Bytecode was developed for both compilation and interpretation, while MSIL was developed explicitly for JIT compilation" - This talking about how Java code gets compiled down to bytecode AND that bytecode gets interpreted. Am I correct? Does MSIL not get interpreted to be executed?

Answer (score 2):

There are not that much differences. Both are intermediate formats of the code you wrote. When executed, the Virtual machines will execute the intermediate language managed that means that the Virtual Machine controls the variables and calls. There is even a language which I don't remeber right now that can run at .Net and Java the same way.

Basicly, it's just another format for the same thing

Edit: Found the language (besides Scala): It's FAN (http://www.fandev.org/), looks very interesting, but no time yet to evaluate

Comment: Scala can be compiled to target the JVM or the CLR, generating bytecode or MSIL respectively.

Comment: Good to know, but I found another language a month ago or so when reading DZone: Found it! See edit of my post

Answer (score 2):

CIL aka MSIL is intended to be human-readable. Java bytecode is not.

Think of Java bytecode as being machine code for hardware that does not exist (but which JVMs emulate).

CIL is more like assembly language - one step from machine code, while still being human-readable.

Comment: Bytecode is actually very readable as long as you have a hex editor.  It's a pretty simple stack-based language with extensions for direct representation of classes and methods.  I thought that MSIL was lower-level (e.g. registers)?

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Transwiki:List_of_hello_world_programs#CIL
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Transwiki:List_of_hello_world_programs#Java_byte-code

One is the *raw* CIL. The other is *disassembled* byte code.

Bytecode may be reasonably readable if you grok hex, but that's not a design aim.

Comment: "Disassembled" is really the wrong word for it.  "De-encoded" maybe.  Bytecode is unreadable in the .class files merely for compactness.  Countrary to javap's man page, there's no disassembly involved in producing readable bytecode from a compiled class.

Answer (score 2):

Serge Lidin authored a decent book on the details of MSIL: [Expert .NET 2.0 IL Assembler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596463).  I also was able to pick up MSIL quickly by looking at simple methods using [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and [Ildasm (Tutorial)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387(VS.71).aspx).

The concepts between MSIL and Java bytecode are very similar.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, the differences are minute enough to ingore as a beginner. If you want to learn .Net starting from the basics, I'd recommend looking at the Common Language Infrastructure, and the Common Type System.

Answer (score 1):

I think MSIL should not compare to Java bytecode, but "the instruction that comprise the Java bytecodes".

There is no name of disassembled java bytecode. "Java Bytecode" should be an unofficial alias, as I cannot find its name in official document.
[The Java Class File Disassembler](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html) say

> Prints out disassembled code, i.e., the instructions that comprise the Java bytecodes, for each of the methods in the class. These are documented in the Java Virtual Machine Specification.

Both "Java VM instructions" and "MSIL" are assembled into .NET bytecode and Java code, which are not human readable.