# Java and ASP.NET

Tags: jvm, cil

Please can anyone tell me the difference between JVM and MSIL?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95163/differences-between-msil-and-java-bytecode

Answer (score 5):

JVM is the [Java Virtual Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine), the [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) on the Java platform which executes [Java bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode).

MSIL is the Microsoft Intermediate Language, which is currently called the [Common Intermediate Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) (CIL), are the "lowest-level human readable" instructions which is bytecode that is run on the [Common Language Runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) (CLR), the virtual machine on the .NET platform.

The JVM and MSIL is not an apples to apples comparison, because one is a virtual machine, and the other is instructions that runs on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

The JVM and MSIL are actually not a good comparison.  MSIL is the intermediate language that all .NET code compiles down to.  The .NET runtime just-in-time compiles the IL into code that can execute on the machine.

MSIL is comparable to Java bytecode.  The Java Virtual Machine (JVM) executes the bytecode in a similar fashion to MSIL on the .NET runtime.  The JVM compiles the Java bytecode down to code that can execute on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read a full length article to get a good answer. And you probably need to clarify if you want a discussion about Java bytecode vs MSIL or the Sun JVM vs the CLR. This should help.[link text](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=957341)