# Bytecode differences in different programming languages

Tags: jvm, bytecode, jit, opcode, pyc

I know several interpreted programming languages ​​(PHP, Python, Java, Smalltalk) are using Bytecode as an intermediate step to execute code.

Is there a difference between the form of Bytecode generated by different languages' interpreters​, as the differences between Assembly opcodes for different machines?

In addition, just to be sure, Bytecode can be used only in interpreted languages, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bytecode is a generic word for the instructions executed by a virtual machine, in the same way that machine language is a generic term for the instructions executed by a real processor. Just as there are many different machine instruction sets, there are many different bytecode instruction sets. Some, like Java bytecode, are a documented part of a platform. All Java virtual machines execute exactly the same bytecode, by definition. Others are just an implementation detail, and differ from version to version.

To answer your last question: no, that is not correct. Java is not an interpreted language; it is just-in-time compiled. C# is similar. Bytecode can be a part of many different architectures.

Comment: So, the practical answer is yes? Java bytecode is different from Python bytecode? Is the differences significant between these popular languages?

Comment: Yes they are completely different. There are few if any similarities.

Answer (score 1):

As Ernest mentioned it is vendor dependent bytecode implementation from different languages. While there are already attempts to standardize bytecode. Have alook at solution from Microsoft [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)

Worth to mention [LLVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) compiler which becoming glue for different bytecodes providing optimizing compilation to any CPU instruction set.

Comment: Isn't CIL just a .NET-specific bytecode? What standardization attempt in it, compared to the Java's JIT bytecode?

Comment: Yes it is low level .NET, also have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95163/differences-between-msil-and-java-bytecode